# Targeting .NET 4.0 in VS2010 with .NET 4.5 Installed

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

Well, I already looking around and can't find a good answer.
(In case if this is a duplicate question...)

I plan to install .NET Framework 4.5 on my machine where VS2010 Sp1 already installed. 
I develop some applications using WPF. I read that many WPF's bugs on .NET 4.0 were fixed on .NET 4.5.

And from MSDN it stated:

> The .NET Framework 4.5 replaces the .NET Framework 4. When you install the .NET Framework 4.5 on a system that has the .NET Framework 4 installed, the assemblies are replaced.

So, my question is:

If I develop an WPF apps that still targeting .NET 4.0 and run it on machine which is .NET 4.5 installed, will I still get the .NET 4.0 bugs??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you target 4.0, you'll still be running on top of .NET 4.5 with all of its bug fixes.

Comment: As my thought, I just need to confirm it. Thank you.